# Declaring multidimensional array for mysql_fetch_assoc

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to create an array which will follow something like this

```
array(
    [Matt => 3],
    [Tom => 7]),
    //etc
)
```

I want this set up so I can use it with a mysql_fetch_assoc() such as

```
    $i=0;
    while($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){

        $Array[$i] = $data['name'];  // sore name as part of array
        $Array[$i][0] = ($data['number']; // keep number with the name.
        $i++;

    }
```

This does not work . I was unable to do so with a array_push. Can someone please guide me? Is my array declaration wrong or even important?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
    $Array[$data['name']] = $data['number']; // keep number with the name.
}
```

that assumes no duplicate names - which might not be the intention and I've misread your question...

alternatively

```
while($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
    $Array[] = array($data['name'] => $data['number']); // keep number with the name.
}
```

The latter is something that you can do with pdo fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); [see here](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php)

Comment: `PDOStatement::fetchAll()` won't produce an associative array like that but I think your second example is probably what the OP wants. +1

Comment: @Phil PDO will if you use the PDO::FETCH_ASSOC const. on fetchAll you will get a numerically indexed array of tuples which contains an associative array of the fields and their values.

Comment: Yes, but it won't give you `Matt => 3`. It will give you `name => Matt, number => 3`

Comment: yeah - think that oversight means bed-time :P BUT easier to work with in most cases...

Comment: Thank you both! The former was what I needed.

Comment: make sure you accept the answer mattyd. it helps your reputation when asking future questions.

Answer (score 0):

I can't quite tell exactly what you want but does this help?

```
$array = array();
while ($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $array[$data['name']] = $data['number'];
}
```

This will produce an array like the following (`print_r` style)

```
Array
(
    [Matt] => 3,
    [Tom]  => 7
)
```